# Record User Actions on 2007Excel VSTO in .ini file Using C#

Tags: c#, vsto, excel-2007

How to record user performed actions on 2007Excel VSTO in .ini file using C#.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you subscribe to all the pertinent events and log them using a syntax of your own making.

The bad news is that the event model is not comprehensive.

Without a more detailed question, that's the most complete answer. Without accepting answers on some your previous questions, you're unlikely to get much help from the community.